# Draw circles on bingo map around push pins with the specified radius value

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, geometry, html5-canvas, markers

net application in which I am retrieving latitude,longitude and quantity value available at that location. i am able to display push pins on map based on locations and able to draw circles around the push pins. if Circles are big then it indicates that the large quantity is available at that location or at the pushpin location. I am able to display those but circles are overlapping which is fine as locations are very close but my question is there any way to display intersection of circles with dark color as it is showing white or transparent  color .Please have a look at the code , help would be highly appreciated. i ahve retrieved data in code behind and passed it to the java script using string builder. lats[],longs[] and value[] are latitude,longitude and quantity values.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3_aspx"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head id="Head1" runat="server">
      <title>Display on Map</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          function GetMap() {

              var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapMap"),
                                {
                                    credentials: "Bingo map key",
                                    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(42.274260, -83.365717),
                                    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
                                    zoom: 8
                                });

              // var backgroundColor = new Microsoft.Maps.Color(10, 100, 0, 0);
              var backgroundColor = new Microsoft.Maps.Color(10, 0, 0, 0)
              var borderColor = new Microsoft.Maps.Color(150, 200, 0, 0);
              //Earth's mean radius in KM is 6371km.
              var R = 6371, lat1, long1, d, circlePoints = new Array();

              // var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(43.3504, -84.5603);
              var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(42.274260, -83.365717);

              for (var i = 0; i < lats.length; i++) {
                  var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lats[i], longs[i]);
                  var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc, { text: FcN[i], typeName: 'PinColor', textOffset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-45, 0) });
                  //Display circle
                  lat1 = (lats[i] * Math.PI) / 180;
                  long1 = (longs[i] * Math.PI) / 180;
                  var d = parseFloat(Value[i]) / R;
                  for (x = 0; x <= 360; x += 5) {
                      var p2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0);
                      brng = x * Math.PI / 180;
                      p2.latitude = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(d) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(brng));
                      p2.longitude = ((long1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(lat1), Math.cos(d) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(p2.latitude))) * 180) / Math.PI;
                      p2.latitude = (p2.latitude * 180) / Math.PI;
                      circlePoints.push(p2);
                  }
                  var polygon = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(circlePoints, { fillColor: backgroundColor, strokeColor: borderColor, strokeThickness: 0 });
                  map.entities.push(polygon);
                  map.entities.push(pin);

              }

              map.setView({ center: location, zoom: 10 });

          }
      </script>

   </head>
   <body id="body" runat="server">
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div id="mapMap" style="position:relative;width:600px; height:600px">  
       <script type="text/javascript">GetMap();
       </script>    
          </div> 
           </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to display circles the I way I wanted to display on bingo Map.
It was just few modification . I am attaching code to help others who is looking for such example.

I am attaching the block which I have modified.

```
for (x = 0; x <= 360; x += 5)
                  {
                      var p2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0);
                      brng = x * Math.PI / 180;
                      p2.latitude = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(d) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(brng));
                      p2.longitude = ((long1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(lat1), Math.cos(d) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(p2.latitude))) * 180) / Math.PI;
                      p2.latitude = (p2.latitude * 180) / Math.PI;
                      circlePoints.push(p2);
                      var polygon = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(circlePoints, {fillColor:backgroundColor,strokeColor:borderColor,strokeThickness: 1 });
                       map.entities.push(polygon);

                  }
                  circlePoints = [];
```